# What is the procedure to calculate the vibrationally resolved UV-Vis spectrum in solvent with Gaussian?

Tags: gaussian

I followed the tutorial reported [here](https://pogorelov.scs.illinois.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/UV-Vis-Spectra_Calculation_Tutorial-PogorelovLab.v1.web_.pdf) to calculate the vibrational resolved spectrum in vacuum. The spectrum seems ok and it is actually close to the experimental one.

However, I would like to add the solvent to have closer peaks wavelengths to the experiments. I first simply tried to add the solvent in the three steps, however I obtain a spectrum with an extra peak that I don't know where it comes from. I then read on the Gaussian [website](https://gaussian.com/scrf/) that the calculation of the excited state in solvent shouldn't be done with the opt keyword but this didn't solve my problem.

So, can someone provide the step-by-step calculation of the vibrationally resolved UV-Vis spectrum in solvent with Gaussian?